# How can I make Featured Image/Thumbnail responsive?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm looking for some code to make the thumbnail of my images responsive in the way that they resize when I resize my browser if that makes sense. So I found this code and it kind of works:

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    $image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(),’thumbnail’ );
    echo '<img width="100%" src="' . $image_src[0] . '">';
}
```

The only problem is that it gives me this error:

> Warning: Use of undefined constant ’thumbnail’ - assumed '’thumbnail’'

(this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

So what I'm wondering is if there is a new way to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have copied this code from somewhere else.

So in `$image_src` image size `thumbnail` have copied Single Quotes.

Remove that Quotes and try the default editor's Single or Double quote and try again.

Comment: Thanks! It was indeed copied haha